# Redux generates 3 empty arrays of object when I reload the page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

When I refresh my app it generates 3 arrays (I supposed cause of I got 3 `ProductCard` in my `pages/index.tsx`)
[image]

Why is this happening?

// index page

```js
import PageLayout from '@/components/page-layout';
import ProductCard from '@/components/product-card';
import { getSugarProducts } from '@/data/graphqlQueries';
import { GetServerSideProps } from 'next';
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import { RootState } from 'src/redux/store';

import { Grid, Box, Button, Text } from '@chakra-ui/react';
import NextLink from 'next/link';

const IndexPage = ({ sugarProducts }) => {
  console.log(sugarProducts);
  return (
    <PageLayout title='Home' description='Fake Sugar - sklep internetowy'>
      <Grid
        templateColumns={{
          base: 'repeat(1, 1fr)',
          md: 'repeat(2, 1fr)',
          xl: 'repeat(3, 1fr)',
        }}
        gap={4}
      >
        {sugarProducts.map((product) => (
          <Box key={product.slug}>
            <ProductCard
              title={product.title}
              brand={product.brand}
              price={product.price}
              coverImage={product.coverImage.url}
              id={product.id}
              slug={product.slug}
              stock={product.stock}
            />
          </Box>
        ))}
      </Grid>
    </PageLayout>
  );
};

export default IndexPage;

export const getServerSideProps: GetServerSideProps = async () => {
  const data = await getSugarProducts();

  return {
    props: {
      sugarProducts: data.sugars,
    },
  };
};
```

/product-card
got an error here: error(1) - `Expected 1 arguments, but got 2.` Why it happens? I got an array of `card` in `initialState`?

```js
import {
  Box,
  Center,
  useColorModeValue,
  Heading,
  Text,
  Stack,
  Image,
  Icon,
  HStack,
  Tooltip,
  Flex,
  Link,
} from '@chakra-ui/react';
import { FiShoppingBag } from 'react-icons/fi';
import { SugarProductSchema } from '@/types/sugar-product-schema';
import NextLink from 'next/link';
import toast, { Toaster } from 'react-hot-toast';
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import { addToCart, selectId } from 'src/redux/slices/cartSlice';
import { RootState } from 'src/redux/store';

export const ProductCard = ({
  title,
  brand,
  price,
  coverImage,
  id,
  slug,
  stock,
}: SugarProductSchema) => {
  const selectIdOfTheProduct = useSelector(selectId);
  console.log(selectIdOfTheProduct);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const handleAddToCart = (id, title) => {
    dispatch(addToCart({id, title})); // return an object with id and title
    toast.success('Dodano produkt do koszyka');
  };
  return (
    <Center py={12}>
      <Toaster />
      <Box
        role={'group'}
        p={6}
        maxW={'330px'}
        w={'full'}
        bg={useColorModeValue('white', 'gray.800')}
        boxShadow={'2xl'}
        rounded={'lg'}
        pos={'relative'}
        zIndex={1}
      >
        <Box
          rounded={'lg'}
          mt={-12}
          pos={'relative'}
          height={'230px'}
          _after={{
            transition: 'all .3s ease',
            content: '""',
            w: 'full',
            h: 'full',
            pos: 'absolute',
            top: 5,
            left: 0,
            backgroundImage: `url(${coverImage})`,
            filter: 'blur(15px)',
            zIndex: -1,
          }}
          _groupHover={{
            _after: {
              filter: 'blur(20px)',
            },
          }}
        >
          <Image
            rounded={'lg'}
            height={230}
            width={282}
            objectFit={'cover'}
            src={coverImage}
          />
        </Box>

        <Stack pt={10} align={'center'}>
          <Text color={'gray.500'} fontSize={'sm'} textTransform={'uppercase'}>
            {brand}
          </Text>
          <NextLink href={`/products/${slug}`} passHref>
            <Link style={{ textDecoration: 'none' }}>
              <Tooltip
                label='Wyświetl produkt'
                fontSize='md'
                bg='gray.50'
                hasArrow
                placement='left'
              >
                <Heading fontSize={'2xl'} fontFamily={'body'} fontWeight={500}>
                  {title}
                </Heading>
              </Tooltip>
            </Link>
          </NextLink>
          <HStack>
            <Text fontWeight={800} fontSize={'xl'}>
              {price}PLN
            </Text>
            {/* <Text textDecoration={'line-through'} color={'gray.600'}>
              $199
            </Text> */}

            <Tooltip
              label='Dodaj do koszyka'
              fontSize='md'
              bg='gray.50'
              hasArrow
            >
              <Flex as='span' textAlign='center'>
                <Icon
                  as={FiShoppingBag}
                  w={6}
                  h={6}
                  cursor='pointer'
                  onClick={() => handleAddToCart(id, title)} // add id and title to cartSlice reducer
                />
              </Flex>
            </Tooltip>
          </HStack>
        </Stack>
      </Box>
    </Center>
  );
};

export default ProductCard;
```

/redux/slices/cartSlice.ts

```js
import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
// import type { PayloadAction } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import { RootState } from '../store';

const initialState = {
  data: [],
  totalAmount: 0,
  totalCount: 0,
};

export const cartSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'cart',
  // `createSlice` will infer the state type from the `initialState` argument
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    addToCart: (state, action) => {
      state.data.push({ ...action.payload }); 
    },
  },
});

export const { addToCart } = cartSlice.actions;

// selector
export const selectId = (state: RootState) => state.cart.data;

export default cartSlice.reducer;
```

store.ts

```js
import cartReducer from 'src/redux/slices/cartSlice';
import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    cart: cartReducer,
  },
});

export type RootState = ReturnType<typeof store.getState>;
export type AppDispatch = typeof store.dispatch;
```

OK i managed to save id and title to this array `data[]` (idk i restared my dev server several times and closed chrome) but still I generates 3 arrays with object, with the same values when I click this this icon which `dispatch` addToCart
[image]

// edit 2
when I refresh the app there is 3 empty array, when I click on addToCart Icon in console.log there is 3 array with 1 object in every array, when I click other product with other Id it again console.log 3 array but with 2 objects with id of the first product and object with the second id and title btw.

[image]

Comment: Its not generating 3 array, the component where you're logging is just rendering 3 times.

Comment: I assume they have the same values?

Comment: when I refresh the app there is 3 empty array, when I click on addToCart Icon in console.log there is 3 array with 1 object in every array, when I click other product with other Id it again `console.log` 3 array but with 2 objects with id of the first product and object with the second id and title btw.

Comment: added an image at the bottom of description

Comment: It just rendering before your new add to cart is on state -- then it is rendering twice after it is on the state.

Comment: There is only one array on state - you're just logging it 3 times because of your component renders.

Comment: That's how redux works? I previously used Zustand for that and it didn't console log 3 arrays everytime I clicked add to cart icon, but 1 array with these objects of products' id.

Comment: Your component will render on any state change or prop update. This is probably causing at least one of the rerenders `export const getServerSideProps: GetServerSideProps = async () => {
  const data = await getSugarProducts();

  return {
    props: {
      sugarProducts: data.sugars,
    },
  };
};`

Comment: ok I get it. So I was just freaking out that it shouldn't happen, lol :D Thank you.